# If Freyr and Odin knew that Hel would use the dishonoured humans to fight against them, why would they still send the humans there?

Tags: ragnarok

Freyr and Odin know that Hel would use the fallen humans in Helheim to fight against them. If they knew about this, why would they want their own downfall?